# Curl get 404 if url contains accented chars

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl to download an image from url in this way:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$html = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$html) {
    echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
    echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
    return false;
}
else{
    return $html;
}
```

If the `$url` is like `http://example.com/image.jpg` my function works and i'm able to use the html returned.

If the `$url` is like `http://example.com/imagè.jpg` my function doesn't work and print this lines (obviously the file exists and i'm able to see it in browser!):

```
cURL error number:22
cURL error:The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to encode the image name part of the URL before you use it in your cURL request:

```
$rest_of_the_url = "http://example.com/";
$image_name = "imagè.jpg";
$url = $rest_of_the_url . urlencode($image_name);
```

Comment: Just tried! It prints me:`cURL error number:6`
`cURL error:Could not resolve host`

Comment: Don't urlencode the http:// example/cpm/ part. Use urlencode on the end of the URL. Otherwise, it encodes / characters.

Comment: Sorry, I mean you need to url encode the image name.

Comment: You can't encode the whole URL, otherwise you end up with `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fimag%C3%A8.jpg`

Comment: What is the actual URL so I can reproduce the error myself?

Comment: Yeah. I'm not seeing your error unfortunately. I did have to comment out the line with the undefined `$userAgent` though.

Comment: I commented too. Now I get this new error: `cURL error number:22`
`cURL error:The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden`

Comment: I am not seeing that either. The cURL request is reading in the image just fine. I'm going to post my full test code for you to throw in a test document and try for yourself and then I'll change the URL once you've gotten it.

Comment: @wogsland Please remove the real url

Comment: It works with your example. Then i separate my url using implode but it gives me 403 error even if the url is correct, i print it after using in curl. Don't know why tomorrow i'll work again

Comment: Ok it works! The problem was only the query I did not setting utf8 charset. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using UTF8 encode function php